# Compare two dataframes with same index using one column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following two dataframes (samples). I'd like to know which companies had their sales changed between the two dataframes. For example, AAPL is different in the second dataframe.

```
        Sales  52W High  52W Low
Root
A       4.81B   -0.1072   0.1082
AA     12.81B   -0.3124   0.0709
AABA  266.05M   -0.2038   0.0437
AAL    43.52B   -0.3285   0.1131
AAN     3.61B   -0.0208   0.4716
AAOI  321.80M   -0.5196   0.5195
AAP     9.42B   -0.0153   1.1190
AAPL  255.27B   -0.0101   0.5210
AAXN  385.40M   -0.1005   2.3432
ABB    35.52B   -0.1870   0.0987
        Sales  52W High  52W Low
Root
A       4.81B   -0.1019   0.1149
AA     12.81B   -0.3527   0.0082
AABA  266.05M   -0.2212   0.0208
AAL    43.52B   -0.3487   0.0797
AAN     3.61B   -0.0196   0.4733
AAOI  321.80M   -0.5478   0.4303
AAP     9.42B   -0.0216   1.1218
AAPL  243.89B   -0.0286   0.4957
AAXN  385.40M   -0.0806   2.4171
ABB    35.52B   -0.1838   0.1030
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Pandas - Find difference between two data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647534/python-pandas-find-difference-between-two-data-frames)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This you can using `ne` [(not equal)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.ne.html)

```
df1.Sales.ne(df2.Sales)# the one mask as True is the different 
Out[482]: 
Root
A       False
AA      False
AABA    False
AAL     False
AAN     False
AAOI    False
AAP     False
AAPL     True
AAXN    False
ABB     False
Name: Sales, dtype: bool
```

Comment: I was going to suggest merge the columns and subtracting them, but this is cleaner.