# How to add new column based on a match condition on two pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframe d1 and d2 as follows:
d1

```
A   B   C    D
X   6   7   23
Y   3   4   35
B   5   8   45
D   11  7   15
L   10  1   5
```

d2

```
A   C 
Y   4 
L   1 
D   7
```

and want new column in d1 E as follow:

```
A   B   C   D   E
X   6   7   23  0
Y   3   4   35  1
B   5   8   45  0
D  11   7   15  1
L  10   1   5   1
```

new column E is added based on the condition of data in column A & C of d2 matched with data in column A & C of d1, number of rows are different in booth dataframe.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647534/python-pandas-find-difference-between-two-data-frames/48647840#48647840 almost same:-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll be using `merge` (for a LEFT OUTER JOIN) with an indicator:

```
d1['E'] = (d1.merge(d2, on=['A', 'C'], how='left', indicator=True)
             .eval('_merge == "both"')
             .astype(int))
d1
   A   B  C   D  E
0  X   6  7  23  0
1  Y   3  4  35  1
2  B   5  8  45  0
3  D  11  7  15  1
4  L  10  1   5  1
```

---

Here's an inefficient approach using tuples conversion with `isin` checking:

```
d1['E'] = (
    d1[['A', 'C']].apply(tuple, axis=1).isin(d2.apply(tuple, axis=1)).astype(int))
d1
   A   B  C   D  E
0  X   6  7  23  0
1  Y   3  4  35  1
2  B   5  8  45  0
3  D  11  7  15  1
4  L  10  1   5  1
```

I'd rather post this myself, that way I get to tell you I don't recommend its use.

Comment: how can we do? if we want to add yes or no instead of 1 and 0.

Comment: After running this code, use `df['E'] = np.where(df['E'] == 1, 'yes', 'no')`.