# Comparing 2 data frames across multiple columns and saving the non-matched rows

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have 2 dataframes, say *all_df* and *incomplete_df*.

I need to compare these 2 dataframes across 3 columns (Fname,Lname, DoB) and find the rows in *all_df* that are NOT in *incomplete_df*.  I need these rows to then be saved into new dataframe and from there exported to an excel spreadsheet.

This is my first journey into python so any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647534/python-pandas-find-difference-between-two-data-frames

Comment: Thanks for the reference