# adding new rows to one data frame from another on a condition [python]

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have two csv files and I am trying to combine them in one based on a condition.

they both have the 'Import_ID' column which gives unique id for each row.
What I need to do is to check if the Import_ID from df1 already exist in df2, if not add this row, else skip it. It would be best if it would be done without the loops or iterrows().

```
df1
 Import_ID            State                  ProductName
0     7027514279_100    716        TRANSCEND ESD220C 240GB SSD extern
1   7027514279_200.1    716        INTELLINET 48,3cm 19Zoll Steckdosenleist
2   7027514279_200.2    716        INTELLINET 48,3cm 19Zoll Steckdosenleist
3   7027514279_200.3    716        INTELLINET 48,3cm 19Zoll Steckdosenleist
4   7027514279_200.4    716        INTELLINET 48,3cm 19Zoll Steckdosenleist

and df2
   Import_ID          State                  ProductName
0     7027329459_100    716        BROTHER MFCJ6530DW MULTI-FUNCTION (AT)
1   7027514279_200.2    716        INTELLINET 48,3cm 19Zoll Steckdosenleist
2   7027514279_200.3    716        INTELLINET 48,3cm 19Zoll Steckdosenleist
3     7027329459_400    716        BROTHER LC-3219XLY Tinte Gelb (1500 S)
4     7027329459_500  20010        BROTHER LC-3219XLBK Tinte Schwarz
```

what I would like it to be is that df1 rows are only then imported when their Import_ID doesn't exist in the df2

```
df2 updated:
 Import_ID          State                  ProductName
0     7027329459_100    716        BROTHER MFCJ6530DW MULTI-FUNCTION (AT)
1   7027514279_200.2    716        INTELLINET 48,3cm 19Zoll Steckdosenleist
2   7027514279_200.3    716        INTELLINET 48,3cm 19Zoll Steckdosenleist
3     7027329459_400    716        BROTHER LC-3219XLY Tinte Gelb (1500 S)
4     7027329459_500  20010        BROTHER LC-3219XLBK Tinte Schwarz
5     7027514279_100    716        TRANSCEND ESD220C 240GB SSD extern
6   7027514279_200.1    716        INTELLINET 48,3cm 19Zoll Steckdosenleist
7   7027514279_200.4    716        INTELLINET 48,3cm 19Zoll Steckdosenleist
```

so in the example the df1 rows 1 nad 2 are not copied, because they already exist.

I tried by creating a temp file where I would store all of the rows from df1 that don't exist in df2 but it didn't work.

```
temp = numpy.where(file_in['Import_ID'] not in finalData['Import_ID'], file_in)
```

I don't know what else I should try , since I am pretty new to python.

Comment: concat both then drop duplicates - `pd.concat([df2,df1]).drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)` ?

Comment: @anky_91 if df2 is all unique row , that is fine , if it is not , we will drop partial information from df2

Answer (score 3):

Using `merge` with `indicator` more [info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647534/python-pandas-find-difference-between-two-data-frames/48647840#48647840)

```
s=df1.merge(df2,how='left',indicator=True)
pd.concat([df2,s.loc[s['_merge']=='left_only'].drop('_merge',axis=1)])
```

Comment: when I try your solution it gives me this error:
ValueError: You are trying to merge on float64 and object columns. If you wish to proceed you should use pd.concat

Comment: @AmilaBečirović Please check your df dtype , to see same columns name have the same datatype

Comment: strange, few of them don't have the same dtype, although the other data frame was created in the same way as the first one :/

Comment: @AmilaBečirovića you need to convert it to the same dtype :-)

Comment: I changed dtype, but now it only shows the rows from df1 and the rows from df2 if different are no where to be seen

Comment: I did it like this and it works apparently :
`s = pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True)
s = s.sort_values('Import_ID', ascending=False)
s = s.drop_duplicates(subset='Import_ID', keep='first')`