# how to iterate each row of one dataframe and compare with rows in another dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe, comparison

I have two dataframes:

DF1:

```
ID     v1           v2         v3
289  1455.0        2.0        0.62239  
289  1460.0        0.0        0.46037  
289  1465.0        4.0        0.41280 
290  1470.0        0.0        0.39540 
290  1475.0        2.0        0.61809 
290  1475.0        2.0        0.61809
```

DF2:

```
ID     v1           v2         v3
289  1423.0        2.0        0.62239  
289  142Q.0        0.0        0.46037  
289  14FW.0        4.0        0.41280  
290  14Q3.0        0.0        0.39540  
290  1453.0        2.0        0.61809 
290  1454.0        2.0        0.61809
```

I want to iterate each row in DF1 with every row in DF2 and see if it is in DF2, something like:

```
for row in results_01.iterrows():
    diff = []
    if row not in results_02:
        add different one to 'diff'
        print(diff)
```

I know the logic but not sure how to do this, new to Python, can anyone help me? Many thanks.

Comment: What should the output be from the given inputs? There are no rows that match completely in the given sample

Comment: I answered below, but curios why you call the similar rows ‘diff’?

Comment: @LiorCohen My bad, I wanted to say if 'row not in results_02', then add to diff, basically I want to find the different rows and not line by line.

Comment: and to answer the first question, this sample data is just an example, I copied somewhere else. @G.Anderson

Comment: You may want to include some rows that do match, otherwise all of the rows you provided would be different so the simplest code would just be `diff=df1.copy()`

Answer (score 1):

The code block you have looks pretty close to what you do in python. Take a row from one dataframe and iterate through the other dataframe looking for matches.

```
for index, row in results_01.iterrows():
    diff = []
    compare_item = row['col_name'] 
    for index, row in results_02.iterrows():
       if compare_item == row['compare_col_name']:
           diff.append(compare_item, row['col_name']
    return diff
```

Here I am taking a specific column value from a row from one dataframe and comparing it to another value from the other dataframe

Comment: Hi I want to compare the whole row instead of one element because I only care about the difference in the row with the same ID :)

Comment: and it gives me error 'IndentationError: unexpected indent'

Comment: This should be fixed for indentation. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily with ‘inner’ merge.

```
intersect = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner')
```

**Edit:**

It turns out that the rows that are in df1 and not in df2 are wanted and not the intersection.
In this case one should use the [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) pandas method.
Here is SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48647840/3700626) that deals with it.

Comment: I got error 'SyntaxError: invalid character in identifier'

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it (maybe not the most efficient) would be to append the dataframes together and then drop duplicates, like so:

```
full_df = df1.append(df2)
full_df = full_df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

Comment: why full_df returns nothing? I tried 'results_01.equals(results_03)' and it gives False which means two files are different

Comment: Hi I tried two different files and it gives me 4 rows, I compared manually but found them are the same (pair to pair), any chance you know what's going on?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean... Didn't you want that?