# Compare 2 dataframes Pandas, returns wrong values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are 2 dfs

datatypes are the same

```
df1 =

ID city      name    value
1  LA        John    111
2  NY        Sam     222
3  SF        Foo     333
4  Berlin    Bar     444

df2 =

ID  city      name   value
1   NY        Sam    223
2   LA        John   111
3   SF        Foo    335
4   London    Foo1   999
5   Berlin    Bar    444
```

I need to compare them and produce a new df, only with values, which are in df2, but not in df1

By some reason results after applying different methods are wrong

So far I've tried

```
pd.concat([df1, df2],  join='inner', ignore_index=True)
```

but it returns all values together

```
pd.merge(df1, df2, how='inner')
```

it returns df1

then this one

```
df1[~(df1.iloc[:, 0].isin(list(df2.iloc[:, 0])))
```

it returns df1

The desired output is

```
ID city      name    value
1   NY        Sam    223
2   SF        Foo    335
3   London    Foo1   999
```

Comment: Check this out. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647534/python-pandas-find-difference-between-two-data-frames

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) by all columns without first and `indicator` parameter:

```
c = df1.columns[1:].tolist()
```

Or:

```
c = ['city', 'name', 'value']

df = (df2.merge(df1,on=c, indicator = True, how='left', suffixes=('','_'))
       .query("_merge == 'left_only'")[df1.columns])

print (df)
   ID    city  name  value
0   1      NY   Sam    223
2   3      SF   Foo    335
3   4  London  Foo1    999
```

Comment: Nice soln, nice use of `query` here to get a concise answer

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
print("------------------------------")
print(df1)

df2 = DataFrameFromString(s, columns)
print("------------------------------")
print(df2)

common = df1.merge(df2,on=["city","name"]).rename(columns = {"value_y":"value", "ID_y":"ID"}).drop("value_x", 1).drop("ID_x", 1)
print("------------------------------")
print(common)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
------------------------------
   ID    city  name  value
0  ID    city  name  value
1   1      LA  John    111
2   2      NY   Sam    222
3   3      SF   Foo    333
4   4  Berlin   Bar    444
------------------------------
   ID    city  name  value
0   1      NY   Sam    223
1   2      LA  John    111
2   3      SF   Foo    335
3   4  London  Foo1    999
4   5  Berlin   Bar    444
------------------------------
     city  name  ID  value
0      LA  John   2    111
1      NY   Sam   1    223
2      SF   Foo   3    335
3  Berlin   Bar   5    444
```