# Find difference between two pandas dataframes when both contains same rows but one dataframe contains it more than once

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two pandas dataframes

df1

```
jon,12,NewYork
jon,12,NewYork
james,14,LA
```

df2

```
jon,12,NewYork
james,14,LA
```

I want to compare them and get the difference as below

deltaDF

```
jon,12,NewYork
```

I tried `pd.concat([df1,df2,df2],axis=0,sort=False).drop_duplicates(keep=False)` This works fine when there are not duplicates but doesn't give difference when one of the dataframe contains duplicates and other dataframe has single entry. I have also tried the solutions mentioned in [Python Pandas - Find difference between two data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647534/python-pandas-find-difference-between-two-data-frames) but that is also returning empty dataframe in this case

### Similar questions

I think this is not a duplicate question because an answer given to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647534/python-pandas-find-difference-between-two-data-frames) returning empty dataframe for the above scenario.

### Edit

People are telling that this is not possible. Can we do something like this:

Add a column giving the count of occurrence of each row

Convert above df1 to

```
jon,12,NewYork,2
james,14,LA,1
```

Convert above df2 to

```
jon,12,NewYork,1
```

Now I can use all columns as index and subtract the last column.

Comment: how actually your data frames are looking while executing, could you please share that

Comment: when you want to get the difference you have to compare sth. but what do you want to compare if there is a duplicate and only get rid of one? it won't work like you want it to

Comment: @luigigi   In pyspark we have a method like exceptAll() to achieve this. I want something similar in pandas

Comment: @TheGuy I have shared dataframes in the question. Please let me know if you need anything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a new column to catch the duplicates:

```
df1['merge'] = df1.groupby(['0','1','2']).cumcount()

df2['merge'] = df2.groupby(['0','1','2']).cumcount()

pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

Afterwards you can drop the added column again

Comment: Perfect!! I was doing this 
`a = df1.groupby(list(df1.columns.values)).size()`
`b = df2.groupby(list(df2.columns.values)).size()`

`x=a-b`
`x = x.reset_index(name='count')`

`print(x[x['count']>0])`

But yours seems better. Thanks for the help. cumcount is great.

Answer (score 2):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ('jon', 'jon', 'james'),
    'age': (12, 12, 14),
    'city': ('NewYork', 'NewYork', 'LA'),
})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ('jon', 'james'),
    'age': (12, 14),
    'city': ('NewYork', 'LA'),
})


def unique_col(x):
    # generate record uniqueness criteria after grouping
    return ''.join([x['name'], str(x['age']), x['city'], str(x['counter'])])


# calculation of the same items
df1['counter'] = df1.groupby(['name', 'age', 'city']).cumcount() + 1
df2['counter'] = df2.groupby(['name', 'age', 'city']).cumcount() + 1
# unique key after grouped counters
df1['unique_key'] = df1.apply(unique_col, axis=1)
df2['unique_key'] = df2.apply(unique_col, axis=1)
# select items by unique key
df = df1[~df1['unique_key'].isin(df2['unique_key'].tolist())]
df = df.drop(columns=['counter', 'unique_key'])
print(df)

#  name  age     city
#1  jon   12  NewYork
```

See comments. Hope this helps.