# Return rows with different values from another dataframe in columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to return difference between two data frames but in only some columns.

df1:

[image: df 1]

df2:

[image: df 2]

I wrote below to filter difference

```
df = df.merge (saved, indicator=True, how='left').loc[lambda x: x['_merge']!='both']
```

And it returned

[image: returned]

But I want to return rows that are different in only colA and colB instead of filtering entirely identical rows only, so I can get below dataframe;

what I want:

[image: what I want]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647534/python-pandas-find-difference-between-two-data-frames/48647840#48647840

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify parameter `on` in [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for joined columns:

```
df = (df.merge(saved, indicator=True, how='left', on=['colA','colB'])
        .loc[lambda x : x['_merge']!='both'])
print (df)
  colA  colB colC_x colC_y     _merge
2    C     3      Y    NaN  left_only
3    D     4      X    NaN  left_only
```