# How to findout difference between two dataframes irrespective of index?

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes with only 1 column. How can I only find a difference between these 2?

```
df_1 = [ a,b,c,e,g,t,u]
df_2 = [c,e,f,a,b,r]
```

The result should be like this

```
df_result = [g,t,u,f,r]
```

Comment: How are this two variables dataframes? Do they contain strings? Are they numpy arrays?

Comment: df_result = pd.concat([df_1,df_2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647534/python-pandas-find-difference-between-two-data-frames