# Minus of two dataframes with common multi-index

Tags: python, pandas

Have two dataframes, one of them is very large, as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string, random

siz = int(1e10)
random.seed(1234)
a1 = pd.Series((random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(siz)), name='CatA')
a2 = pd.Series((random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(siz)), name='CatB')
val1 = pd.Series(pd.Series(np.random.randint(2, high=10, size=siz), name='Value'))

df_a = pd.DataFrame([a1, a2, val1]).T.set_index(['CatA', 'CatB'])

siz = 1000
random.seed(4321)
b1 = pd.Series((random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase) for _ in range(siz)), name='CatA')
b2 = pd.Series((random.choice(string.ascii_lowercase) for _ in range(siz)), name='CatB')
val2 = pd.Series(pd.Series(np.random.randint(2, high=10, size=siz), name='Value'))

df_b = pd.DataFrame([b1, b2, val2]).T.set_index(['CatA', 'CatB'])
```

- Want to quickly get the difference between the two dataframes based on their index, while keeping `Value` of df_a intact.

  - `df_b` should be eliminated from `df_a`.
  - Both dfs have the same structure. The `Value` of `df_a` should be preserved.
  - The `Value` of `df_b` is dropped.

Tried `df_a.sub(df_b.drop('Value', 1))` ... which doesn't work.

Is there a vectoriz-ed way to do this?

- [Python Pandas - Find difference between two data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647534) is not multi-index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) with inverted mask by `~`:

```
df = df_a[~df_a.index.isin(df_b.index)]
```