# Finding non-matching rows between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a scenario where I want to find non-matching rows between two dataframes. Both dataframes will have around 30 columns and an `id` column that uniquely identify each record/row. So, I want to check if a row in `df1` is different from the one in `df2`. The `df1` is an updated dataframe and `df2` is the previous version.

I have tried an approach `pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)` , but it just combines both dataframes. Is there a way to do it. I would really appreciate the help.

The sample data looks like this for both `dfs`.

`id`  `user_id` `type` `status`

There will be total 39 columns which may have `NULL` values in them.

Thanks.

P.S. `df2` will always be a subset of `df1`.

Comment: So not working first solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48647534), do you try another one too? Also what is reason not working? Is possible add sample data, [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for show your problem?

Comment: Check this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28901683/pandas-get-rows-which-are-not-in-other-dataframe

Comment: @jezrael I have the same problem if you follow the link posted by archer. I have even tried that approach too, but it returns me all of the rows from df1.

Comment: ya, so please add some sample data for see your problem, only [please don't post images of code/data (or links to them)](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: and, by the way, there can be columns with null values in them.

Comment: @jezrael I have 39 columns, how should I post it here?

Comment: No, for sample data need 2-3 columns, here is most important explain why solution `pd.concat([df1, df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)` not working.

Answer (score 1):

If your df1 and df2 has the same shape, you may easily compare with this code.

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.where(df1==df2,True,False), columns=df1.columns)
```

And you will see boolean output "False" for not matching cell value.

Comment: what do you mean by same len size?

Comment: sorry, I mean same shape (number of row & column)

Comment: Upvoted for good answer, but comes with the caveat that checking columns with `NaN`s will still return False regardless. `np.nan == np.nan` => `False`