# Finding the difference between two dataframes in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have two dataframes

**A**:

```
column1 column2 
  abc      2
  def      2
```

**B**:

```
column1 column2 
  abc      2
  def      1
```

I want to compare these two dataframes and find where there are differences and get the value of column1.

So the output should be 'def' in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647534/python-pandas-find-difference-between-two-data-frames) here, you can try [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) method:

```
pd.concat([A,B]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)['column1'].unique().tolist()
```

**Output:**

```py
# if you just want to see the differences between the dataframe
>>> pd.concat([A,B]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
  column1  column2
1     def        2
1     def        1
```

```py
# if you just want to see the differences and with only 'column1'
>>> pd.concat([A,B]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)['column1']
1    def
1    def
Name: column1, dtype: object
```

```
# if you want unique values in the column1 as a numpy array after taking the differences
>>> pd.concat([A,B]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)['column1'].unique()
array(['def'], dtype=object)
```

```
# if you want unique values in the column1 as a list after taking the differences
>>> pd.concat([A,B]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)['column1'].unique().tolist() 
['def']
```

Comment: Added an answer. Let me know if it works for you. It will give a list as an output. If it does please accept/check-mark the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
pd.concat([A,B]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```