# Compare two DataFrames and get the differences between them as output

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare

I have two dataframes as per below:

```
df1 = [['tom', 10],['nick',15], ['juli',14]]
df2= [['juli', 14],['daniel',15], ['tom',10], ['tom',10]]
```

Please note that the dataframes might not have the same index order, but I would like to receive the differences between them as an output.

So I would expect the output to be:

```
['nick',15]
['daniel',15]
['tom',10]
```

If possible, I would like to know which data frame contains each value. In the example provided above, the first item (`['nick',15]`) belongs to `df1` and the others to `df2`.

Bonus: Is there a way to export the output to Excel?

Comment: Are these lists of lists or DataFrames?

Comment: Why is tom 10 in this result? Do duplicate rows in the same table count as separate? Also related [Python Pandas - Find difference between two data frames](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48647534/15497888)

Comment: ['tom', 10] should be on the result because there are 2x ['tom', 10] on df2 vs. only one of df1

Comment: @danielssl is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69531328/16343464) what you're looking for?

Comment: @mozway Tried your answer, but not working properly... It returns an error to me

Comment: @ mozway

    output = (df1.assign(idx=df1.groupby(cols).cumcount()).merge(df2.assign(idx=df1.groupby(cols).cumcount()),on=list(df1.columns+['idx'],indicator=True, how='outer').drop('idx',axis=1).query('_merge != "both"')))

TypeError: list() takes no keyword arguments

Comment: Well you need to use dataframes as input, you said those were dataframes, not lists. Check the update

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming this input:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['tom', 10],['nick',15], ['juli',14]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['juli', 14],['daniel',15], ['tom',10], ['tom',10]])
```

You could use `merge` with the `indicator` option.

The rationale here is to create an additional column with an index per group to identify the duplicates.

```
cols = list(df1.columns)
(df1.assign(idx=df1.groupby(cols).cumcount())
    .merge(df2.assign(idx=df2.groupby(cols).cumcount()),
           on=list(df1.columns)+['idx'],
           indicator=True,
           how='outer')
    .drop('idx', axis=1)
    .query('_merge != "both"')
   #.to_excel('output.xlsx')  ## uncomment to export as xlsx
)
```

output:

```
        0   1      _merge
1    nick  15   left_only
3  daniel  15  right_only
4     tom  10  right_only
```