# MemoryError when getting differences between data frames

Tags: python, pandas

I am using a solution in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647534/python-pandas-find-difference-between-two-data-frames) to get the difference between two data frames:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,3],'B':[2,3,4,4]})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1],'B':[2]})

dfx = df1[~df1.apply(tuple, 1).isin(df2.apply(tuple, 1))]
```

Data frame `df1` is about 1Gb and `df2` is about 100Mb. I get a "MemoryError" around the function `apply`.

Is this normal and what is the workaround, if any?

Comment: Why not try the `merge` method in the accepted answer? `dfx = df1.merge(df2,indicator = True, how='left').loc[lambda x : x['_merge']!='both']`

Comment: This solution gives similar error ```numpy.core._exceptions.MemoryError: Unable to allocate 735. MiB for an array with shape (96378858,) and data type int64```