# Find rows differences between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes that have the same structure/indexes.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'column_a': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
    'column_b': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
    'column_c': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
})
df1.set_index('id', drop=False, inplace=True)
```

and

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    'column_a': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
    'column_b': [5, 4, 3, 2, 1],
    'column_c': [5, 4, 10, 2, 1]
})
df2.set_index('id', drop=False, inplace=True)
```

And I would like to get this result:

[image]

```
expected = pd.DataFrame({'id': [3], 'column_a': [3], 'column_b': [3], 'column_c': [10]})
```

I tried using for-loop, but I need to deal with a large data load, and it didn't become so performant...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `merge`, filtering on the indicator:

```
>>> (df2.reset_index(drop=True).merge(df1.reset_index(drop=True), 
                                      indicator="Exist",
                                      how="left")
                               .query("Exist=='left_only'")
                               .drop("Exist", axis=1)
     )

   id  column_a  column_b  column_c
2   3         3         3        10
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for could be possibly be answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647534/python-pandas-find-difference-between-two-data-frames).

Using the `drop_duplicates` example from that thread,

```
pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

you can end up with the following DataFrame.

```
    id  column_a  column_b  column_c
id                                  
3    3         3         3         3
3    3         3         3        10
```

Albeit this approach will retrieve rows from both DataFrames.