# Find delta between two dataframes python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes:

[image]

I am trying to compare these dataframes and find the delta out (what's not in both of them). I have tried compare but that needs same indexes and columns, which won't here. How do I go about this?
I am a newbie to pandas and trying to learn.

Comment: Is column b always `value {a}`?

Comment: Just noticed that the space between "value" and the number changes, but this isn't reflected in the result.  Is that deliberate?

Comment: As a one-liner with `pd.merge`: `pd.merge(df, df1, how="outer", indicator="compare").query("compare != 'both'").drop("compare", axis=1)`  Alternatively: `comp = pd.merge(df, df1, how="outer", indicator="compare"); comp.loc[comp["compare"].ne("both")]`

Comment: column b is some value attached to a that does not change. A and B can be looked at as a key value pair.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**:

The quickest way I have found to do this is to use .drop_duplicates(). I have found it to be very efficient on iterating over large datasets but for smaller datasets there's likely not much a speed difference against other methods. For example

```
df1=df1.drop_duplicates(keep="first") 
df2=df2.drop_duplicates(keep="first") 
pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

Based on the answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647534/find-difference-between-two-data-frames)

Note: The "keep=False" parameter means to drop every duplicate pair from the set, which will leave only the difference, which you're asking for.